# How to remove textbox highlight on button click (Java)

Tags: java, text, jbutton, highlight

The highlight to which I'm refering:

[image]

When i click on the JButton that uses following code:

```
    public static JButton addButton(JPanel panel, String text, Point pos, int width, int height, ActionListener action)
{
    JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.setBounds(pos.x, pos.y, width, height);
    button.addActionListener(action);
    button.setVisible(true);
    button.setBackground(new Color(255, 137, 58));
    button.setForeground(Color.white);
    button.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(196, 96, 29), 2));
    button.setRolloverEnabled(true);
    panel.add(button, 3, 0);

    return button;
}
```

The textbox highlights afterwards. Is there a simple way to remove this effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this

```
button.setFocusPainted(false);
```

Comment: could you add some explanation as to how it is going to help

Comment: Documentation 
  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setFocusPainted(boolean)

Comment: Thanks for the help lad ;)

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali write some explanation in your answer otherwise it could be tagged as a low quality post and may eventually be deleted. Also you won't attract up votes for this kind of answer. Always try to give an explanation for your suggested code quoting from external sources.